# Best way to check if a file is saved already in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm making a word processor. The problem is how can I check if a file is saved in C#? Like when the user click the **X** button, the program will check whether the file is saved, if yes then it will close the file, otherwise the program will ask user to confirm if the user want to close the file.

I think using MD5 hash can be a practical way, but is this the best way?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a 'dirty flag' that keeps track of whether the file has been modified. It's set to false at first, and as soon as the user modifies the content, the flag is set to true. Once the modifications have been saved, the flag is set to false again. The weakness of this method is that is you modify the content after saving, then modify it again to be similar to the saved version, you won't know it's the same.

Alternatively, you can use a hashing function. It's good because it really compares content, but it might cause performance issues with large files (you should test whether it's a problem). There's also the possibility of collisions, but they shouldn't be a problem unless you pick a really bad hashing function.

Of course it's also possible to combine the two methods and use a dirty flag when the user modifes the content, then the hashing function if the dirty flag is set to true and the user tries to close the application.

Better ways might exist, but here's my two cents on the matter.

Comment: If the `dirty` flag is _dirty_ then it is **dirty**.  Hashing would only be useful say for when the file is modified outside of the user scope such as multi-user edits (OneNote) but then I would probably use some version field rather than comparing my humungous file

Answer (score 0):

You can use comtypes..

Below code snippet is copy pasted from

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9f978a32-845c-4823-9780-2f184ba435a1/how-to-check-if-word-document-has-changes?forum=vsto

```
using ComTypes = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

 

ComTypes.IPersistFile persistFile = (ComTypes.IPersistFile)documnet;

//Checks an object for changes since it was last saved to its current file.

if (persistFile.IsDirty)

{

//do your stuff

}
```

Comment: The //do your stuff thing is when the file is saved or not saved?

Comment: Not saved. File is dirty.

Comment: Though absolutely true, bit of an overkill just to get the `IsDirty` flag